# How to create vocabulary from Arrays of Strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, vocabulary

I have to make a vocabulary with unique words of some texts. I have texts converted to Arrays of Strings. Now I want the Array list with only unique words. So the first step, convert the first Array of Strings to a `List<Strings>` (I guess?) where all double words are filtered out. That is my first step, how do I do this, and do I use a `List<String>` or another `String[]`?

Second, the next String[] I 'read-in' should update the vocabulary `List<String>` but ONLY add new words from the text.

It must look something like:

```
public List<String> makeVocabulary(String[] tokens){
     List<String> vocabulay = new ArrayList<>;
     //add unique words from 'tokens' to vocabulary
     return vocabulary;

}
```

**TL;DR:** how do I convert a whole bunch of `String[]` to one `List<String>` with only the unique words from the `String[]`'s?

Comment: You create a new vocabulary inside of this method, wouldn't this set the vocabulary to null each time you run this code?

Comment: Also, is that a typo of vocabulary in your declaration of `List<String> vocabulay = new ArrayList<>;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon review of your code, it appears that you would be clearing vocabulary each time you run this command, so it can only be done once. If you'd like to make it more modular, do something like this:

```
public class yourClass
{
    private List<String> vocabulary = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> makeVocabulary(String[] tokens)
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++ )
            if( !vocabulary.contains( tokens[i] ) )
                vocabulary.add(tokens[i]);
        return vocabulary;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! How do I make it so that the String[] get converted in a int[] that gives for every word out of the vocabulary the amount of times the word is in the vocabulary? Because for example the word "you" is four times in the text but only one time in the vocabulary, how do I make a int[] of wordFrequencies from a text?

Comment: You asked to have it be unique words, so there should never be more than **one** occurrence in the Array. This means that the amount of times it would be in the array is always 1.

Comment: True, for the vocabulary this is completely the answer I was searching for. But is there a way so that I can convert now the String[] tokens to int[] wordFrequencies from the vocabulary?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. So you want to check to see if for example the word "totally" is in the vocabulary multiple times? This would require you to abandon the `makeVocabulary()` method that I just gave you...

Comment: For example, for String[] I add is "Hello you are a you" so the vocabulary is "hello you are a" because the 2nd you is not included. I want a int[] for the String[] that is [1, 2, 1, 1] because 'you' is two times in the vocabulary. But when I add String[] "hello you are beasty" the vocabulary should update to "hello you are a beasty" and the int[] for the next text should be [1, 1, 1, 0, 1], how do I fix this? The vocabulary is working already 100%! Thanks a lot!

Comment: So you could write code inside of your makeVocabulary that sets `wordFrequencies[i] += 1`;

Comment: There should be a method countWordFrequencies(String[] token) that makes for the vocabulary a int[] of how many times the words of the vocabulary occur in the token. So the String[] is converted to an int[] of wordFrequencies.

Comment: You would be unable to do it as asked, since makeVocabulary only allows for one instance of each String. You can call a method before it that calls countWordFrequencies

Comment: I know in the vocabulary the word only occurs once, but in the String[] tokens the word occurs more than once. So the String[] tokens can be converted in [1, 0, 2, 3, 4] which means, one time the first word of the voc, 0 times the second word, 2 times the third etc. etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97331/discussion-between-totalcare-and-liquidsystem).

Answer (score 1):

For determining unique tokens, use a `Set` implementation...

```
public List<String> makeVocabulary(String[] tokens){
 Set<String> uniqueTokens = new HashSet<String>();
 for(String token : tokens) {
    uniqueTokens.add(token);
 }
 List<String> vocabulay = new ArrayList<String>(uniqueTokens);
 return vocabulary;

}
```

Comment: Depending on the requirement, he may be forced to use `List<String>` and `ArrayList<String>`, so wouldn't it make sense to follow his way of setting it up and just using an if-test to see if it is contained in the `List<String>`?

Comment: The order is very important, check the reply I gave to liquidsystem above. But thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: Its an additional logic and overhead if you want to use List, whereas Set ensures order. TotalCare, what do you mean by order?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve your goal is to make use of the Set class as opposed to a List of strings. You could look into that e.g. like the code below.

```
public List<String> makeVocabulary(String[] tokens){
 Set<String> temp = new HashSet<>;
 //add unique words from 'tokens' to temp
 List<String> vocabulary = new ArrayList<>;
 vocabulary.addAll(temp);
 return vocabulary;
}
```

If you can live with Set as the return type of makeVocabulary, you can just return temp.